# Vuforia based Unity3d Game blurry camera

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-camera, vuforia

I had been trying a app that I developed in Unity3d on multiple android devices.
For some reason in some devices the camera seems blurry.Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO works well on all of my Android devices. Read the article below for more info.

https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Camera-Focus-Modes

> We encourage using FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO in your applications whenever it is available on the device. When setting this mode, if the return value of setFocusMode() is TRUE your application will provide sharp camera images for both superior rendering, as well as for robust tracking performance.

Comment: What if, android device dont support FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO or any other mode, for example Nexus 6p. @user1226019